# How to write a unit test to see if a property is set to indexed=False?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

If I have a model like this:

```
class Person(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  age = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
```

How can I test if `age`'s index is set to False?

Comment: In TDD any expectations should be captured.  Turning unnecessary indices off, adds to performance and reduces writing costs on GAE.

Comment: What about a simple `self.assertFalse(Person.age._indexed)` -- any reason that wouldn't work for you?

Comment: @AlexMartelli that works wonderfully.  Add it as an answer please.

Comment: Done, it is an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
self.assertFalse(Person.age._indexed)
```

without any complication.

Answer (score 0):

```
properties = Person._properties
assertEqual(properties["age"], GenericProperty('age', indexed=False))
```

depending on what else is happening with your code, there may need to be different attributes in your assert statement.

Use `Person._properties` to see what you should be expecting. Alternately, you could parse just `indexed=False`, or just the bool from the _properties output and use a much simpler assertion that provides a much more specific test.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. It fails with `BadFilterError: invalid filter: Cannot query for unindexed property age.`

Comment: catch that error and treat it as a success maybe? because in a way your error shows you that "age" is not indexed. Which was your goal, no?